# How to create TypeScript type definitions for a local AMD JS module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amd, typescript-typings

Our project is migrating from JavaScript to TypeScript. I want to define type definition for a specific JavaScript AMD module, and I'm not quite sure how. Here's the simplified code:

module.js

```
define(function(require, module, exports) {
    exports.func = function(a) { return a.toString(); }
});
```

Basically, I want to import this module from TypeScript code and have the `func` variable in it to have a type `(arg: number) => string`. What is the most clean way to do this?